# Storyboard - go back to tab bar controller from modal view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, modalviewcontroller

I have a tab bar controlled application.

And I have a flow that goes something like this:-

`Tab 1 View Controller (initial view controller) - "presented modally" View controller - "pushed" View Controller 2 - "pushed" View Controller 3 - "presented modally" View Controller 4`

Basically, it is `Modal - Push - Push - Modal`

Now, I want to go back to Tab 1 View Controller(initial view controller) from View Controller 4 (that was presented modally).

View controller 4 should have a "back button" which when pressed will lead me back to Tab 1 View Controller.

How do I do that? I tried:-

1. Creating a whole new `UIWindow` and placed things back. Problem is the back button which I placed on View Controller 4 comes back on Tab 1 View Controller. Weird. Tried removing it with various methods, didn't go away.
2. Use the `popToViewController` method, but the navigation controller is different because of last modal view controller.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: You mentioned "Tab 1" vc twice: when said you want to go back to it and when said it is a problem that the app returns to it which is confusing by itself, not to mention that we have no idea which of the view controllers from this chain is the "Tab 1" vc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I solved it. I needed to climb back down the ladder.

Dismiss `self.navigationController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController`, which was pointing to `UITabBarController`, where `self.navigationController` is from View Controller no. 4 (the last modal view controller).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this on the button that leads to the first tab view controller

```
UIStoryboard *mySB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"[StoryBoardFileName]" bundle:nil];
            UIViewController *vc = [mySB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"[ViewControllerIdentifier]"];
            [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

hope it helps

Comment: The question is how to get back, not how to prolong the vc chain.

Comment: Well this worked, but maybe I tried to "pop" everything back out which was obviously going to be a problem. Now, will everything "under" this "presentation" be cleared? Not exactly sure.